# ReactJS React Router returns GET Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to modify this ReactJS starter kit:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d65d6b29-6dd7-4100-81b1-609e5afce356?SRC=VSIDE

This is my Default file which displays the active route handler.

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */

'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var {Link} = require('react-router');
var Navbar = require('../components/Navbar.jsx');

var DefaultLayout = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <this.props.activeRouteHandler />

      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = DefaultLayout;
```

Here is my App.jsx which contains my router.

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */

'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var {Routes, Route} = require('react-router');

// Export React so the dev tools can find it
(window !== window.top ? window.top : window).React = React;

React.renderComponent(
  <Routes location="history">
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={require('./layouts/Default.jsx')}>
      <Route name="home" path="/" handler={require('./pages/Home.jsx')} />
      <Route name="search" path="/search" handler={require('./pages/Search.jsx')} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>,
  document.body
);
```

Whenever I try to navigate to http://localhost:3000/search, I get a "Cannot GET /search" error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I've been working with React Router for a while now and haven't seen this.props.activeRouteHandler and it's not even in their api.... and also, you don't display anything by putting in an an element tag...should be in `{}` It should be `{this.props.children}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starter-kit seems to work on a old version of react-router, because handler didn't exist since a long time. (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md#route-config)

Try to recode the router with a more recent version of react-router (why not the v2.6), or get an more updated starter-kit.

**React-router GitHub (with upgrade guides) :** https://github.com/reactjs/react-router